# Function Add is continuous (using open sets)

Tags: general-topology, continuity, proof-explanation

Let $\operatorname{Add}: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow R$ and $\operatorname{Add}(x,y) = x + y$. Prove that is continuous using open sets.

Proof: $V \subset R$.

$$(\operatorname{Add})^{-1}(V) = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: \operatorname{Add}(x,y) \in V\} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x + y \in V\}$$

How to prove that $(\operatorname{Add})^{-1}(V)$ is an open set?

Comment: Notice that I put all of $$(\operatorname{Add})^{-1}(V) = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: \operatorname{Add}(x,y) \in V\} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x + y \in V\}$$ between just one pair of double dollar signs. That's the proper way to do that. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $V\subset{\mathbb R}$ be open, and assume $(x,y)\in{\rm add}^{-1}(V)$.  We have to prove that there is a two-dimensional neighborhood $U$ of $(x,y)$ such that ${\rm add}(U)\subset V$.

Let  $z:={\rm add}(x,y)\in V$. As $V$ is open there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $\ ]z-2\epsilon,z+2\epsilon[\ \subset V$. The square
$$U:=\ ]x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon[\ \times\ ]y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon[\ $$
is an open neighborhood of $(x,y)$. Choose an arbitrary point $(x',y')\in U$. A repeated application of the triangle inequality then shows that
$$\bigl|{\rm add}(x',y')-z\bigr|\leq|x'-x|+|y'-y|<2\epsilon\ ,$$
hence
$${\rm add}(x',y')\in V\ .$$